# Conditional chaining with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've tried to implement conditional chaining and this is what I got:

Controller index action code:

```
@range_start = params[:range_start]
@range_stop = params[:range_stop]
Contract.within_range(@range_start, @range_stop)
```

Model code:

```
def self.within_range(range_start = Date.today - 1.month, range_stop = nil)
  self.started_after(range_start).started_before(range_stop)
end

def self.started_after(range_start)
  if range_start.blank?
    self
  else
    self.where('start_date >=?', range_start)
  end
end

def self.started_before(range_stop)
  if range_stop.blank?
    self
  else
    self.where('start_date<=?', range_stop)
  end
end
```

It works, but does not looks good. I tried to improve it a bit using `tap`, without success. How this code can be improved?

UPDATE: In can be converted to inline conditional, but maybe something else can be improved?

```
range_start.blank? ? self : self.where('start_date >=?', range_start)
```

UPDATE2: If `range_stop` is not set, this code is not really works, `started_after` condition does not apply.

What I have to return from `started_before` to do not loose first condition?

Comment: range_start has a default value as Date.today - 1.month. How can it be blank then?

Comment: Yes, right now I don't need this condition, removing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want try to clarify the purpose of doing conditional chaining this way: the idea is to hide condition inside some method, and chain methods, so resulting method will be simple.

It is possible, but child of ActiveRecord::Base class can't be chained itself. Only relation can be chained.

So instead of doing this:

```
def self.started_before(range_stop)
  if range_stop.blank?
    self
  else
    self.where('start_date<=?', range_stop)
  end
end
```

one should do this:

```
def self.started_before(range_stop)
  if range_stop.blank?
    scoped
  else
    self.where('start_date<=?', range_stop)
  end
end
```

Only one change: `self` was replaced with `scoped`, and now method always returns a scope, and can be chained.

Thank to this article for hint: http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/

Answer (score 10):

Time has passed and the solution of denis.peplin is already deprecated. Otherwise it's right, you need a relation for chaining. So instead of using `scoped` you should use `all` like this:

```
def self.started_before(range_stop)
  if range_stop.blank?
    all
  else
    where('start_date<=?', range_stop)
  end
end
```

But you could also write this as a scope for more brevity:

```
scope :started_before, ->(range_stop){ range_stop.blank? ? all : where('start_date<=?', range_stop) }
```

Comment: Scopes always returns chainable objects, so no need for `all` inside scope. Try this: `scope :started_before, ->(range_stop){where('start_date<=?', range_stop) if range_stop.present?}`

Comment: `.all` does not return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`; it **executes the query and returns an array**. So if the function returns an `.all` it means that it is not chainable. Also, returning an `.all` means that the function does not always return the same type - which will very likely be problematic in the future due to them having different interfaces.

Note: This might differ between rails 4.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

In the ruby world there is a thing called `scope` that does what you want.

```
scope :started_after, lambda {|x| where("start_date >=?", x) }
scope :started_before, lambda{|x| where("start_date <=?", x) }
```

Or in one line

```
scope :starts_between, lambda{|start,finish| where("start_date >=? AND start_date <= ?", start, finish) }
```

Scopes are an active Record feature so you can simply call:

```
Contract.starts_between(date1, date2)
```

When you want the secound parameter conditional:

```
def self.within_range(start, finish = nil)
  data = Contract.started_after(start)
  data = data.started_before(finish) unless finish.nil?
  data
end
```

Comment: I need to share this functionality between two classes, can I specify scope inside module?

Comment: nope you cant share a `scope` between two models because they work on database level

Comment: but they are the state of the art way to add conditions to a query because you can stash them like `Model.scope1.scope2.scope3`

Comment: It there any way to chain methods?

Comment: that is method chaining! You can chain 2 scopes in a row if if you want.^^ Like I said: `Model.scope1.scope2.scope3`

Comment: That is obvious, but what about methods that was not defined via scope?

Comment: You can also do that with other stuff like Strings `"string 1337".gsub("1", "31").downcase.other_method`

Comment: I specified this in UPDATE2 to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I Added this:

```
scope :dynamic, -> (chain=nil) { chain.present? ? chain.call : nil }
```

And now you can use it like this

```
conditional_scope = x ? Model.scope1 : Model.scope2
Model.scope3.dynamic(conditional_scope).scope4
```